# Can archive.org's Wayback Machine ignore some query terms?

Tags: internet-archive

I'd have a single page web application that uses both query terms to control content shown to users as well as target-style hash fragments, which prevents encoding the query terms in the hash.  An example link:

https://example.com/page?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3#target

My understanding is that for every combination of values of `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, the Wayback machine will attempt to store a different version of the page... which is a bit of a waste of storage for a single page application, and which could lead to missing coverage of some combinations of those parameters.

I'm wondering whether I could use `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/page" />` to tell the Wayback machine to ignore all the variants of the page, and if I did, would I get something other than a 404 when requesting https://example.com/page?foo=1&bar=2&baz=3 ?

Or instead of using `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, are there other query term names I could use that the Wayback machine would ignore both during crawls and requests?

Answer (score 3):

Wayback Machine will archive query strings and alternate URLs no matter what the canonical is. Take for example the [highest voted question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/6083675) ("stackoverflow.com/q/11227809"), which has been archived at [43 (or more) different URLs](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809*), including ones with an extra segment ("stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/####") and query strings ("stackoverflow.com/q/11227809?lq=1"). The canonical URL is the one with the title slug.

The space doesn't matter (and it's not even your space!). I would just suggest allowing all variations of your URL to be saved since that's the most user friendly.